# result is stored for presentee and does not shows absent and for the next day it overwrites the already stored values

Tags: python, csv, face-recognition

```
def attendance(self, i, n, d, g):
    with open("attendance.csv", "r+", newline="\n") as f:
        dataList = f.readlines()
        name_list = []
        for line in dataList:
            entry = line.split((","))
            name_list.append(entry[0])
        if((i not in name_list) and (n not in name_list) and (d not in name_list) and (g not in name_list)):
            now = datetime.now()
            d1 = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            dates = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            f.writelines(f"\n{i},{n},{d},{g},{dates},{d1},Present")
#tracking attendance through face recognition and storing the values in a csv file...
```

This is the original data set
[image: THIS IS THE ORIGINAL DATA SET]

This is the data generated through face recognition
[image: THIS IS THE DATA GENERATED THROUGH FACE RECOGNITION]

The problem is that it took these two employees attendance and for the next day it is not getting recorded.

This is the expected output
[image: This is the expected output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some sample lines from your CSV file (in orig text format) and also show what your expected output file should look like

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, the reason for asking for the data in text format (rather than a screenshot) is to allow us to copy/paste it into an `attendance.csv` file to test your code

Comment: Are there two files?  Your input and output are in different formats?

Comment: @MartinEvans  yes there are two different files.. first one is the data stored in the database and second one is the data stored through face recognition.. which only gives certain columns of that first file.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your problem, the question is not clear, it would help if you improved your explanation of what is needed

Comment: @MartinEvans As you can see in the second pic jasmini and sumanth have been already recorded on the date 24th may .
the problem is even if those two person faces have been recognised on 25th  they are not getting stored in the csv file..  this is the problem